# Hide image field completely in drupal 7 module

Tags: forms, drupal, module, field

I'm trying to setup a form where some fields needs to be hidden depending on the user role. I'm doing this in my own module using hook_form_FORM_ID_alter. No problem with common text, email  or link fields (e.g. $form['field_companyname']['und'][0]['value']['#type']='hidden'). But for an image field or a multiple value file field the usual way won't work.

Anybody can give me a clue?

Comment: Just found the solution myself -- setting the '#type' attribute on the first level of the field to 'hidden' will do it and not the '#type' attribute inside the language and/or delta element.

Answer (score 0):

I think your going about this the wrong way. Since your limitation is based on roles you can just use the permissions system. Check out [field permissions](http://drupal.org/project/field_permissions) module.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use #access for the element instead of just hiding the field.

For field company name it will go like this:

```
$form['field_companyname']['#access'] = FALSE;
```